# ggplot2 select axis label based on randomly generated variable name

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a scatterplot displaying two variables that are randomly selected from my dataframe using the following method:

```
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=df[,sample(2:503, 1)], y=df[,sample(2:503, 1)]))
```

However, I am unable to figure out which column is being randomly generated. I'd like the column heading to be displayed on the X and Y axis's.

Comment: Do you really want to *independently* sample x and y values?

Comment: @Gregor I'm not sure I understand what you mean by independently sampling x and y values. I believe my code was to choose a specific column of data at random, but I may have misunderstood that sample function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could sample column names rather than columns, and then use `aes_string` to specify your plotting aesthetics using strings rather than expressions:

```r
reprex::reprex_info()
#> Created by the reprex package v0.1.1.9000 on 2018-02-08

library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1)

vars <- names(mtcars)
ggplot(mtcars, aes_string(sample(vars, 1), sample(vars, 1))) + geom_point()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
```

first some data

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(1000), ncol = 10))
```

generate the sampled columns data frame first:

```
df %>%
  select(c(sample(1:10, 1), sample(1:10, 1))) -> df2
```

use the colnames as xlab and ylab:

```
ggplot()+
    geom_point(aes(x = df2[,1] , y = df2[,2]))+
    xlab(colnames(df2)[1])+
    ylab(colnames(df2)[2])
```

[image]